# Terraform | variable instance_type in module should be type string, got map

Tags: terraform

I am getting below error when I am trying to do use data block for AMI's:-

Error: module.ec2-wf.var.instance_type: variable instance_type in module ec2-wf should be type string, got map
Error: module.ec2-wf.var.ami: variable ami in module ec2-wf should be type string, got map
make: *** [validate] Error 1

Below is my terraform structure:-

```
project
    modules
        app1
        app2
        app3
        common
            global-variables.tf
            main.tf
            makefile
            provider.tf
            vpc.tf
        global
            acm
            alb
            asg
            ec2
            efs
            lc
            rds
            redis
            subapp
                ec2
                    main.tf
                    makefile
                    provider.tf
                    variable.tf
```

project/modules/global/subapp/ec2/main.tf

```
module "ec2-wf" {
    source = "../../../global/ec2"

    name                    =   "${var.name}"
    db_remote_state_bucket  =   "s3-terraform-state"
    db_remote_state_key     =   "subapp/ec2/terraform.tfstate"
    key_name                =   "${lookup(var.key_name, terraform.workspace)}"
#    ami                     =   "${lookup(var.ami, terraform.workspace)}"
#    instance_type           =   "${lookup(var.instance_type, terraform.workspace)}"
    ami                     =    "${var.ami}"
    instance_type           =    "${var.instance_type}"

    tags = {
        Name        =   "${var.project}"
        Environment =   "${lookup(var.env, terraform.workspace)}"
    }
}
```

project/modules/global/ec2/variables.tf

```
variable "instance_type" {
    description = "This describes the  Map the environment whether it is dev/test/prd etc"
}

variable "ami" {
    description = "This describes the  Map of Availability Zones to deploy"
    default     =   ""
}
```

Comment: What are the values passed in for those variables? The error is inconsistent with the default value provided for one and lack of default value provided for the other.

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine to me. Potentially it looks like it is looking at the commented lines for some reason? As the uncommented versions look fine.

```
#    ami                     =   "${lookup(var.ami, terraform.workspace)}"
#    instance_type           =   "${lookup(var.instance_type, terraform.workspace)}"
```

To make sure, you could always specify the type (like below). If that doesn't work, delete the commented lines and see if it still happens.

```
variable "ami" {
  type = string
}
```